# Is there any 'Open Enrypted File Container' Format?

Tags: aes, file-encryption, confidentiality

Tools that create 'encrypted file containers' use open encryption standards like AES to encrypt container contents, however the container format is proprietary, I am guessing, so need the same tool to decrypt the data. So, is there any Open 'Encrypted File Container format'? I mean I should be able to use one tool to create the container, maybe another to mount/decrypt the container if they both support the same standard?

Comment: I removed the product recommendation request is this is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Archives and emails come to mind.

**Archive formats:** both [Zip](https://www.iso.org/standard/60101.html) and [7Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/7z.html) are open standards that support encryption (though *how well* they do encryption is up for debate).

**Email formats**: [S/MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME), aka [Cryptographic Message Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652), aka [PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) is an open standard for a container format that supports cryptographic signing and encryption (both symmetric encryption like AES, and public-key encryption like RSA). S/MIME is widely supported by email clients such as Outlook, Thunderbird, and probably many others.

[OpenPGP Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) is another such container format designed for email which supports the same crypto operations as S/MIME. In addition, many people use PGP for encrypting files on disk. In fact all software distributed through a linux package manager uses the PGP format for its crypto wrapper. The most common tool for reading / writing PGP files is called GnuPG aka GPG, but others tools exist as well.

---

**TL;DR**: Yes, there are many such Open 'Encrypted File Container formats' which can be understood by many different tools. The ones that come to mind are zip-like things, and email-like things, but I'm sure there are more examples.

Comment: Came here to recommend OpenPGP. It's standardized (including the crypto providers) with multiple cross-platform and open-source implementations, and uses high-quality cryptography. Unlike S/MIME, it's widely used for file encryption, and unlike ZIP and 7ZIP, its *primary* and well-reviewed purpose is encryption and signing.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Web Encryption [RFC 7516](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) is an IETF standard that can do what you are looking for, it can handle AES in addition to other crypto algorithms.

> JSON Web Encryption (JWE) represents encrypted content using JSON-
> based data structures [RFC7159].  The JWE cryptographic mechanisms
> encrypt and provide integrity protection for an arbitrary sequence of
> octets.

There implementing of JWE in multiple  languages for example in Java  you can use [nimbus](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwe-with-shared-key)